# Entity property is null even with value entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

So for some reason when I try to do `db.SaveChanges` it says the property Username is not allowed to have null value inserted yet it is not null when I use debugger. The item Username property has a string in it...

```
public void fvAddUser_InsertItem()
{
    var item = new InventarioCiclico.xUtilizador();

    TryUpdateModel(item);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (InventarioCiclicoContext db = new InventarioCiclicoContext())
        {
            if (db.xUtilizador.Any(u => u.Username == item.Username))
            {
                Page.ClientScript
                    .RegisterStartupScript(
                        this.GetType(),
                        "ShowToast",
                        "ShowToast('Erro','topCenter','error', 'Utilizador já exsiste.', '2000')",
                        true
                    );
            }
            else
            {
                xColaborador c = new xColaborador();
                c.Nome = (fvAddUser.FindControl("txtNome") as TextBox).Text;
                c.Email = (fvAddUser.FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox).Text;
                item.xColaborador.Add(c);

                db.xUtilizador.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Page.ClientScript
                    .RegisterStartupScript(
                        this.GetType(),
                        "ShowToast",
                        "ShowToast('OK', 'topCenter','success', 'Utilizador adicionado com sucesso.', '2000')",
                        true
                    );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using database first, this is the xUtilizador class

```
public partial class xUtilizador
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public xUtilizador()
    {
        this.Activo = true;
        this.xAcesso = new HashSet<xAcesso>();
        this.xColaborador = new HashSet<xColaborador>();
    }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public bool Activo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UltimoAcesso { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<xAcesso> xAcesso { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<xColaborador> xColaborador { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

I also had to create partial and metadata classes to update the default value in database

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(Metadata.UtilizadorMetadata))]
    public partial class xUtilizador
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public bool Activo { get; set; }
    }

 public class UtilizadorMetadata
    {
        [StringLength(8)]
        [Display(Name="Username")]
        public string Username;

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public bool Active;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Also I just noticed the Username StoreGeneratedPattern is set to Computed for some reason and I never gave it any default values on database..

Comment: Can you show us `TryUpdateModel()` and `InventarioCiclico.xUtilizador` ?

Comment: I updated post with the class but not sure about TryUpdateModel(), it was generated by formview insert method cause I have ItemType defined as xUtilizador

Comment: if `TryUpdateModel()` is not updating object Username property it's going to be null. So checking it is important.

Comment: Oh i see, i used debugger and yes it updates the object with the value i insert on textbox, it has value until savechanges

Comment: `public partial class xUtilizador` is marked as partial. Is there any other part of it ?

Comment: Updateed post with more info

Answer (score 2):

The problem was username was being set as Computed on the model on StoreGeneratedPattern. Make sure it is set to none to not give null exception on insert.